# Как вытащить число из строки? php

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

{"10":"OK"} как из этой строки получить число 10?

Comment: а) Это строка? б) 10 всегда на первой позиции и в кавычках?

Comment: Читайте http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php

Comment: Также можно читать про [сканнер строк](https://secure.php.net/manual/ru/function.sscanf.php)

Comment: json_decode ничего не дает, мне нужно число 10

Comment: Чем json_decode не угодил?

Comment: @dakemu, он возвращает объект, а мне нужно число. пробовал через get_object_vars, но выходит ошибка. других вариантов как распарсить строку нет

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<?php
 $array = json_decode('{"10":"OK"}', 1);
 echo key($array);
```

Answer (score 5):

> Как вытащить число из строки?

```
$str = "1 ромашка, 2 ромашка, 3 ромашка, 5!";
preg_match_all("/\d+/", $str, $matches);
print_r($matches); // [1, 2, 3, 5]
```

---

> {"10":"OK"}

Это json. И парсить его нужно, как json.

В php для этого есть функция [json_decode](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.json-decode.php):

> mixed json_decode ( string $json [, bool $assoc = false [, int $depth = 512 [, int $options = 0 ]]] );

Обратите внимание на второй параметр: `bool assoc = false`

Если в качестве второго парметра передать `true`, результатом парсинга будет не объект, а массив.

```
$arr = json_decode('{"10":"OK"}', true); // ['10' => 'OK']
$keys = array_keys($arr); // ['10']
echo $keys[0]; // 10
```

Answer (score 4):

Простейший код, работает для любой строки, вытаскивает все цифры.

```
<?php
$str = '{"10":"OK"}';
$strWithoutChars = preg_replace('/[^0-9]/', '', $str);
echo $strWithoutChars;
?>
```

Comment: Какой-нибудь флаг `g` не надо?

Comment: Зачем тут флаг, если работает без флага?
Проверить всегда можно тут http://phptester.net/

Comment: В данном случае правильнее сказать  "оставляет", а не "вытаскивает". "Вытаскивает" `preg_match_all('~\d+~', $s, $matches)`.